# Is a callback in a lazy var okay to do in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

```
lazy var headerView: WatchlistModifierHeaderView = {
    let view = WatchlistModifierHeaderView()

    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: HEADER_VIEW_HEIGHT).isActive = true

    view.tapEventer.handler = { [unowned self] in
        print("HeaderView tapped")
    }

    return view
}()
```

Here is an example. I like this style because everything pertaining to the view is captured in the lazy var. However, I am curious if the variable won't deinit because of the callback.

At the end of the day, I need to read up on memory, init, and deinit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks fine to me. If you actually end up using `self` in the callback as long as you keep that `unowned` or add a `weak`, it shouldn't cause a retain cycle and will deinit correctly.